# Custom lightning-icon won't render properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, svg-icon

I'm trying to add a custom lightning-icon to my experience cloud lwc module, but I can't make it render properly. The custom icon is basically a blue background color with a white dash on the middle.

I followed the steps described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-icon/documentation

I've uploaded an .svg image with a  tag containing an id as a static resource, just like the documentation said, but the image will render only the blue color without anything else. Then, I change the .svg file (as I had noticed that the first image I had uploaded was square, instead of circular), and now the icon won't render at all.

If I try to open the file from the static resource on my org settings it will show the image properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting my head around this issue a lot, I found out it was actually the code on the .svg file itself.

I used an online service to convert a .png file to .svg, and this caused a lot of weird code on the .svg file. LWC couldn't properly work with those files, and that's why it didn't render.

I ended up coding a .svg file myself (the image I needed was simple) and this ended up working fine.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a problem of referencing your static resources in the component module of lwc.But you observe that the icon is visible when opening in personal org environment, that means *your static resource may not be "public" in its cache control settings.*

Go to Setup-->static resource---> Open your static resource file---> Click Edit and re-upload it---> Select "Public" in the **cache control** settings dropdown and Save!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the cache was actually on public. The issue ended up being the .svg file itself.